# How to match column data to row data?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sports dataset that reads as follows:

```
season  team   tm   shk   dgs   brs   cts   cws  avg_pt_marg
2015    sharks shk  0-0   1-3   2-0   4-1   3-2    1.2
2015    dogs   dgs  3-1   0-0   2-1   1-1   2-0    3.4
2015    bears  brs  0-2   1-2   0-0   1-3   2-1    -0.2
2015    cats   cts  1-4   1-1   3-1   0-0   2-2    2.0
2015    cows   cws  2-3   0-2   1-2   2-2   0-0    -2.1
2014    sharks shk  0-0   1-3   2-0   4-1   3-2    0.7
2014    dogs   dgs  3-1   0-0   2-1   1-1   2-0    1.8
2014    bears  brs  0-2   1-2   0-0   1-3   2-1    -1.9
2014    cats   cts  1-4   1-1   3-1   0-0   2-2    2.3
2014    cows   cws  2-3   0-2   1-2   2-2   0-0    -3.0
```

I would like to add a column for each row (a season for a team) that contains the average point margin for a team's opponents.

This is calculated by summing the number of games played against a team (during that season) multiplied by that team's point margin (during that season) divided by the total number of games played (in that season).

For example, for 2015 `sharks,` the average point margin for a team's opponents would be `((4 x 3.4)+(2 x -0.2)+(5 x 2.0)+(5 x -2.1)) / 16.`

How do I calculate this column and then add it to the dataframe?

Like this:

```
season  team   tm   shk   dgs   brs   cts   cws  avg_pt_marg opponent_marg
2015    sharks shk  0-0   1-3   2-0   4-1   3-2    1.2
2015    dogs   dgs  3-1   0-0   2-1   1-1   2-0    3.4
2015    bears  brs  0-2   1-2   0-0   1-3   2-1    -0.2
2015    cats   cts  1-4   1-1   3-1   0-0   2-2    2.0
2015    cows   cws  2-3   0-2   1-2   2-2   0-0    -2.1
2014    sharks shk  0-0   1-3   2-0   4-1   3-2    0.7
2014    dogs   dgs  3-1   0-0   2-1   1-1   2-0    1.8
2014    bears  brs  0-2   1-2   0-0   1-3   2-1    -1.9
2014    cats   cts  1-4   1-1   3-1   0-0   2-2    2.3
2014    cows   cws  2-3   0-2   1-2   2-2   0-0    -3.0
```

Comment: I don't follow your logic - why is 2015 team 1 `((4* 3.4)+(2 * -0.2)+(5 * 2.0)+(5 * -2.1)) / 16`  - where do the 4x, 2x ... etc values come from?

Comment: @rg255 So for the first term: 2015 team1 played team2 4 times, which is why I do 4 times the margin of team 2 (3.4). Again, for the second term, 2015 team1 played team 3 2 times, which is why I do 2 times the margin of team 3 (-0.2). Hope that makes more sense!

Comment: ok, so each cell represents games - teams either win or lose - e.g. because tm2 is 1-3 where tm==tm1, we have tm1 winning once, tm2 winning 3 times?

Comment: possible error in your data, where team=="team4", tm=="tm3"

Comment: Oh yeah that is an error. But yes, right idea.

Comment: I've added an answer below - it would be robust to different team names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not pretty, but

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  by(df,list(df$season),function(x){
    tmp=sapply(
      1:nrow(x),
      function(i){
        unlist(
          lapply(
            strsplit(
              as.character(x[i,grepl("tm[0-9]+",colnames(x))]),
              "-"
            ),
            function(y){
              sum(as.numeric(y))
            }
          )
        )
      }
    )
    cbind(
      x,
      "opponent_marg"=colSums(tmp*x[,"avg_pt_marg"])/colSums(tmp)
    )
  })
)
```

resulting in

```
        season  team  tm tm1 tm2 tm3 tm4 tm5 avg_pt_marg opponent_marg
2014.6    2014 team1 tm1 0-0 1-3 2-0 4-1 3-2         0.7    -0.0062500
2014.7    2014 team2 tm2 3-1 0-0 2-1 1-1 2-0         1.8    -0.3909091
2014.8    2014 team3 tm3 0-2 1-2 0-0 1-3 2-1        -1.9     0.5833333
2014.9    2014 team4 tm3 1-4 1-1 3-1 0-0 2-2         2.3    -0.8333333
2014.10   2014 team5 tm5 2-3 0-2 1-2 2-2 0-0        -3.0     0.7571429
2015.1    2015 team1 tm1 0-0 1-3 2-0 4-1 3-2         1.2     0.7937500
2015.2    2015 team2 tm2 3-1 0-0 2-1 1-1 2-0         3.4     0.3636364
2015.3    2015 team3 tm3 0-2 1-2 0-0 1-3 2-1        -0.2     1.1916667
2015.4    2015 team4 tm3 1-4 1-1 3-1 0-0 2-2         2.0     0.2400000
2015.5    2015 team5 tm5 2-3 0-2 1-2 2-2 0-0        -2.1     1.4428571
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that's great!

Comment: I have a question. If my tm1-5, weren't actually named that but instead were names like "Sharks", "Dogs", etc. What would change? Because I see you wrote tm[0-9]

Comment: @yoyoman32 Yes, that part is where I identify the tm1 to tm5. If you had different names then you would have to find the indices of these columns and replace that part of the code.

Comment: If you look, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another not pretty solution, but it's a fairly complex little task - lots of components to it. I use a data.table here - if you're not familiar with them, they are just a pumped up verion of a data.frame giving some extra functionality

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt1)
```

First up, reshape the data to a longer format

```
# Reshape the data
dt2 <- dt1[, melt(.SD, id.vars=c("tm", "team", "season", "avg_pt_marg"))]
```

I also filtered out the cases where team and opponent match. This step also creates a variable for the number of matches/games played

```
# Filter out cases where team and opponent match
dt2 <- dt2[tm != variable,][,
  # Get number of games played
  `:=`("games_played" = as.numeric(tstrsplit(value, "-")[[1]])+
                        as.numeric(tstrsplit(value, "-")[[2]]))]
```

Then the final step to give you the values you want:

```
# Get the team/season averages
dt3 <- dt2[, sum(avg_pt_marg*games_played)/sum(games_played), keyby=.(season, "tm" = variable)]
```

You can merge this in with a data.table join

```
dt1 <- dt1[dt3, on=c("tm", "season")]
```

Giving:

```
    season   team  tm shk dgs brs cts cws avg_pt_marg         V1
 1:   2014 sharks shk 0-0 1-3 2-0 4-1 3-2         0.7 -0.0062500
 2:   2014   dogs dgs 3-1 0-0 2-1 1-1 2-0         1.8 -0.3909091
 3:   2014  bears brs 0-2 1-2 0-0 1-3 2-1        -1.9  0.5833333
 4:   2014   cats cts 1-4 1-1 3-1 0-0 2-2         2.3 -0.8333333
 5:   2014   cows cws 2-3 0-2 1-2 2-2 0-0        -3.0  0.7571429
 6:   2015 sharks shk 0-0 1-3 2-0 4-1 3-2         1.2  0.7937500
 7:   2015   dogs dgs 3-1 0-0 2-1 1-1 2-0         3.4  0.3636364
 8:   2015  bears brs 0-2 1-2 0-0 1-3 2-1        -0.2  1.1916667
 9:   2015   cats cts 1-4 1-1 3-1 0-0 2-2         2.0  0.2400000
10:   2015   cows cws 2-3 0-2 1-2 2-2 0-0        -2.1  1.4428571
```

Comment: Would I setDT(my dataframe here)?

Comment: yes - that is just adding the data.table class to the object